# jQM DateBox add 2 minutes

Tags: datebox, jquery-mobile

I'm using  [jQM-DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/)
with mode = 'timebox' ... for mobile app.
I noticed that when the timebox is open and I click on the plus/minus buttons to change the time, sometimes it adds or removes 2 and 3 times. 
it's like the button continues to be pressed. 
How can I fix it ?

Comment: Show us your code, you are probably having problem with multiple even binding, but I can't be sure unless you show us code example.

Comment: it's not my code... I'm using TimeBox the same as on the site http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/
please try to open it on mobile device and you can see that when you press on the plus/minus buttons it will trigger the change more then once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting repButton: false.  It's a "hold to advance" option that does not always work as expected - I'm still trying to make it work right, but it's still not perfect.